# Flash player crashes in fullscreen, with white screen,

Tags: google-chrome, video, flash-player

When I play a video on youtube it is crashing. On my last laptop there is no problem, on my gf there is no problem either.
I bought this new laptop

- Chrome 33.0.1750.146 m
- Windows 8.1 (64-bit)
- Intel Core i7-3612QM (6MB Smart Cache) 2.1GHz procesor z Turbo Boost do 3.1GHz
- Pamięć 8GB DDR3 1600MHz
- Dyski 256SSD (Solid State Drive)
- Wyświetlacz 15,6-calowy antyodblaskowy FHD  (1920 x 1080)
- Grafika NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M z 2GB GDDR5
- Wi-Fi 802.11a/b/g/n WLAN
- Bluetooth V4.0
- 29' Lg with 2560x1080 resolution and it crashed.

I dont think  it is a problem with my hardware.
Here is screen from the problem!
[image]

I put a border around to see how much blank space is left.
Sound is going but the video stays on the same position as I click to full screen.

```
Adobe Flash Player (2 files) - Wersja: 12.0.0.70
Shockwave Flash 12.0 r0
Nazwa:  Shockwave Flash
Opis:   Shockwave Flash 12.0 r0
Wersja: 12.0.0.70
Lokalizacja:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\33.0.1750.146\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll
Typ:    PPAPI (poza procesem)
     Wyłącz
Typy MIME:  
Typ MIME    Opis    Rozszerzenia plików
application/x-shockwave-flash   Shockwave Flash 
.swf
application/futuresplash    FutureSplash Player 
.spl
Nazwa:  Shockwave Flash
Opis:   Shockwave Flash 12.0 r0
Wersja: 12,0,0,77
Lokalizacja:    C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_12_0_0_77.dll
Typ:    NPAPI
     Wyłącz
Typy MIME:  
Typ MIME    Opis    Rozszerzenia plików
application/x-shockwave-flash   Adobe Flash movie   
.swf
application/futuresplash    FutureSplash movie  
.spl
```

I found out when I disable `pepflashplayer.dll` then it works. But after this change I get advertisments on the videos - which I did not get before.

**Any idea Please? :)**

Comment: Are there some plugins installed on your Chrome ? Have you updated everything on your Computer ? It might be that a antivirus program is blocking flash and therefore you get the above effect. If you try using Internet Explorer on the same video what happens ?

Comment: It could be Chrome’s fullscreen control. Chrome *should* ask you if you want to allow YouTube to go fullscreen, but maybe the prompt is not working/showing. Try going to the page `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#fullscreen` and manually adding it.

Comment: @Synetech I tried on chrome://settings/contentExceptions#fullscreen and everything is "allow"

Comment: @Devid it is happening only in chrome, which is my main browser. I was tring also on ff, safari, opera, ie and maxthon and everywhere is fine as it should be.

Comment: Is flash videos on youtube like this or on every other site that has flash videos ? In the mean time till you find a fix for this you can use this plugin for chrome to watch youtube videos without flash. HTML5 video for YouTube : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-video-for-youtube/dolajcekhnohkpncmhgledbmndjpblei

Answer (score 1):

Disable HW acceleration in Firefox and Chrome/Chromium and Internet Explorer. Disabling the hardware acceleration was what fixed the problem with multiple graphics gards!!!

Here is the link to more details how to disable HW acceleration in the browsers.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/529753/videos-freeze-in-fullscreen-mode-in-chrome-and-firefox